# Tile based map and collision; getting stuck

Tags: java, collision-detection, tile

I'm trying to make my character move around a tile map with collisions. Everything works fine except for one thing. I show you a picture with the problem:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/bcyz5.jpg]
That is, when I reach a tile above then I can not move anywhere. If you come from the left, I can not move either up or down. If you reach the bottom, I can move to the left but not right. And when you reach the right I can move in any direction.

Honestly I have no idea what may be failing. I think it has to do with if (...), because if I change the order, the addresses where I can move change :/

Here I leave some code:

```
boolean collision = false;

if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) {
    for(int i = 0; i < map.GetNumLayers(); i++) {
        if(UpTile(map, i) > 128) {
            collision = true;
        }
    }

    if(!collision) AddPos(0.0f, -vel);
}
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)) {
    for(int i = 0; i < map.GetNumLayers(); i++) {
        if(LeftTile(map, i) > 128) {
            collision = true;
        }
    }

    if(!collision) AddPos(-vel, 0.0f);
}
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) {
    for(int i = 0; i < map.GetNumLayers(); i++) {
        if(DownTile(map, i) > 128) {
            collision = true;
        }
    }

    if(!collision) AddPos(0.0f, vel);
}
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)) {
    for(int i = 0; i < map.GetNumLayers(); i++) {
        if(RightTile(map, i) > 128) {
            collision = true;
        }
    }

    if(!collision) AddPos(vel, 0.0f);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be easier of you separate your game's model from the view shown above. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979) shows one approach, while this more elaborate [example](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/) models a related grid based game.